# Youtube API: How do you get the URL of a video I just uploaded?

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have looked through the YouTube python API and I can't seem to find anything.

Basically all I want to do is upload a video then get the video ID once it has finished uploading.

Is there an easy way to do this in python?

Using V2 of the API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [great example in YouTube API Samples project](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/upload_video.py).
It returns you the [video id](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/upload_video.py#119) in example, so full url would be www.youtube.com/watch?v={videoId} for youtube website. You can use embed url for others, all you need is this video id.

Comment: This looks like it's using the V3 API I'm wondering if it's possible in V2?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a quite tedious way of doing it.

In the end I had to get the uploads of my youtube account and then some gacking to get get my recently uploaded video.

Here's my code:

```
def YouTubeUpload(Loacation):

  # Video upload code here:

  uri = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads'
  GetAndPrintVideoFeed(uri)

def GetAndPrintVideoFeed (Uri):
  yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
  feed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri)
  num = 0

  for entry in feed.entry:
    num += 1
    PrintEntryDetails(entry)
    if (num==1):
        break

def PrintEntryDetails(entry):
    global theurl
    theurl = entry.media.player.url
    print 'Video url: %s' % entry.media.player.url
```

Probally not the greatest way of doing it but it works I guess. I hope this helps anyone that faces the same kind of problem.